# Python 3.3 socket programming error

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

In Python 3.3 I am getting an error while executing this line:

```
print ("Message from server : ") + msg
```

where `msg` is received data from server (Trying to do socket programming as you might guess)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print()` returns `None` in Python 3. So, you're trying to concatenate(or add) `None` with `msg`, which results in an error.

Try string formatting:

```
print ("Message from server : {}".format(msg))
```

Comment: (or even just moving the `+ msg` inside the parens will work)

Comment: @Wooble Yup, if `msg` is always a string then just a `+` is also okay.

Comment: @user2795050 `raw_input` is for py2.x, it has been renamed to `input` in py3.x. Fell free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it worked for you.