# Why isn't my print statement working?

Tags: python

I am just a beginner so bear with me, I am having trouble with my if and print statement. There are 3 choices, A, B or C and this is A:

```
g = 0

ge = ("Gold =")

gh = ("The amount of gold you have is:")

choice3 = input()

if choice3 == "A":
      print("You slide him the coins through the bars.")(g = g - 5)(gh,g)("'Thanks!' He says. You manage to break out with him and escape to New Mexico, Well done, you win!")
```

This is the error message I get:

```
A
You slide him the coins through the bars.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python stuff\Hello World.py", line 111, in   <module>
print("You slide him the coins through the bars.")(g = g - 5)(gh,g)("'Thanks!' He says.     You manage to break out with him and escape to New Mexico, Well done, you win!")
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892619/python-3-3-socket-programming-error

Comment: Why do you define strings using braces?

Comment: g, ge and gh are really great variable names...

Answer (score 5):

It's because `print` always returns `None` after it is called.  See below:

```
>>> print(print('Hi'))
Hi
None
>>>
```

Usually, this `None` is simply ignored by Python.  However, it *does* exist since all functions in Python must return *something*.

Furthermore, at this part:

```
print("You slide him the coins through the bars.")(g = g - 5)
```

you try to call the `None` returned by `print` like a function, giving it the argument `g = g - 5`.

Remember that functions in Python are called by placing `(...)` after them.

[Here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print) is a reference on `print` I think would help you.

Comment: I don't quite understand? What is the fix?

Comment: @Jonathan - Well, that depends on what you want to do.  If you want to print `g - 5` with that string, you can do `print("You slide him the coins through the bars.", g - 5)`.  If you want to change the value of `g`, you need to place `g = g - 5` on its own line.  I didn't include a fix in my post because I don't know what you want.

Comment: Oh, right. Yeah I wanted the value to change. Thanks, that sorted it all out :)

Comment: You're going to change values within a print statement?

Comment: @Jonathan - Oh, well then you can place `g = g - 5` above the print statement line.  In fact, to make it cleaner, you can do `g -= 5`.  It does the same thing as the other code.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use print like that, but use `format` for example, [shown here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)

```
text_is = 'amazing'
print('Your text is {}'.format(text_is))
```

In your case, it could be:

```
if choice3 == "A":
    g = g -5
    print("... {} {} {} 'Thanks!' .. you win!".format(g, gh, g))
```